# In WordPress PHP, can the output from get_header be captured in any way?

Tags: php, wordpress

I notice that with `wp_list_categories()`, `wp_get_archives()` and `wp_list_pages()` one can specify 'echo=0' as part of the parameter string and thus be able to grab the content for further processing before echoing to output stream.

Is there a similar mechanism available for `get_header()`? Alternatively, is there a way of capturing the evaluated header code before it's returned to the browser? What I'm trying to do is modify the contents of the `<title>` markup in the HTML.

Comment: Just saw the title I read `<head>` for some reason

Comment: `<head>` contains `<title>`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a filter hook for the title

```
<?php 
function filter_function_name( $title, $sep, $seplocation ){
  $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );
  return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 ); ?>
```

[Wordpress API for `wp_title` filter hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title)